# ASP.NET MVC return back to previous ajax state (page)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, return

I have simple pages for a testing purpose. So I have an Index page that has a drop-down-list to select a country and a button to search which brings up some information as a list of rows in a table.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetList", "test", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",    
    UpdateTargetId = "showResult"     
}))
```

In my controller, it returns a partial view.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetList(int CountryId)
    {            
        var model = db.Names
            .Include(x => x.Country)              
            .Where(x => x.Country.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();

        return PartialView("PartialPosting", model);
    }
```

In my PartialPosting view, there is a button to call a modal dialog that can submit a note.

```
@model IEnumerable<test.Models.Names>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>                   
        <th>Note</th>            
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {    
        <tr> 
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Button", "button", "test", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#modal-container" })     
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>   

<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tableindex="-1" role="dialog">    
    <div class="modal-content">        
        <div class="modal-body">            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a button is clicked, it goes to a button method in the controller which returns the view that will be shown in a modal for

```
<div class="modal-body">
```

Button method:

```
public ActionResult Button()
    {    
        return View();
    }
```

Button View:

```
@model test.ViewModels.NoteViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostNote", "test", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Note) 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and the PostNote method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostNote(NoteViewModel model)
    {
        //codes

     --> ??  return RedirectToAction();
    }
```

Everything works,
but here is my problem. When a modal submits the note,

1. I want the modal to disappear right away.
2. return back to the previous state where there were a drop-down-list to select a country and a search button && a search result table where I just clicked a button.

Since this involves an ajax response, I am not sure how to bring the correct URL to go back to the previous state.

Comment: What dropdown?, what search button? Where are you wanting to redirect to. You need to show the relevant code.

Comment: Post your `NoteViewModel` through ajax. because posting form does not retain changes.. You have only one Field in NoteViewModel. Just pass `Note` textbox value to PostNote action result on button click..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the form submit in the button view (post note form) to be an ajax form submit and in the PostNote action method which handles the form post data from this form, return a json response. In the success callback of the ajax form submit, simply hide/close the modal dialog and you will see your original buttons and dropdown from your first page.

So update your button view (`Button.cshtml`)to give the form an `Id` which we will use later for wiring up the ajaxified form submit event later.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@model test.ViewModels.NoteViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostNote", "test", FormMethod.Post,new {id="postNoteForm"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Note) 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
<script>
    $(function() {

        $(document).on("submit", "#postNoteForm", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.post($(this).attr("action"),$(this).serialize(),function(response) {

                        console.log('response from ajax call', response);
                        if (response.status === "success") {
                            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                        } else {
                            alert(response.errorMessage);
                        }
                    })
        });

    })
</script>
```

Assuming your `PostNote` httppost action method returns a json response with a `status` & `errorMessage` property (in case of an error)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostNote(NoteViewModel model)
{
  try
  {
    // to do : Save data
     return Json(new {status="success"});
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     return Json(new {status="error", errorMessage = ex.Message });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've just tested the code, console.log appears in the Console but the modal is not closing. I don't think there's a problem with this code: $('#modal-container').modal('hide'); Any idea why it's not executing?

Comment: Make sure `modal-container` is the id of your modal div. It totally worked for me.

Comment: See the working fiddle http://jsbin.com/jewokegube/edit?html,js,console,output. Make sure jQuery is loaded before bootstrap.

Comment: **Also make sure that you have not included jQuery more than once**

Comment: Thanks for your effort Shyju. I tried what you said, and figured out that it's not the jquery or bootstrap issue. My assumption is that, In PartialPosting view, the contents that goes into modal-body is not decorated like what you have done for the fiddle, but instead called from the Button View. So when you try to hide #modal-container from the Button View, it's not tracking the #modal-container since it's in the different view?

Comment: The code I posted in the answer was verified in a local project as it is and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes Shyju. I know it has to work. I was following the example from [here](https://codemagik.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/render-mvc-partial-view-inside-bootstrap-modal-dialog/), and realized that in his example when I press save button it was not closing as well. People say that it is bootstrap version problem, so I updated it to the latest one but the problem still exists. Looking at his example, can you find out why?

Comment: Can you create a sample project with same code and share ?

Comment: damn I just figured it out. I happened to include your code above: '@{
    Layout = null;
}' and it worked. What does that code mean?

Comment: it says to not use any layout when rendering the view. So only the view content will be rendered. nothing else. If you do not do this, It will render your view content inside the layout.